# Retrieve multiple Id from SOSL

Tags: soql, sosl

I have some SF Id (18 char long) coming from a backup system and I have to check if they still exists. Is there a smarter way then do 3 SOQL? Maybe with SOSL?

Something like:

```
public static validate(Id accountId1, Id accountId2, Id opportunityId1) {
    // check if Account exists with accountId1
    // check if Account exists with accountId2
    // check if Account opportunity with opportunityId1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are calling your method so you can adapt this as needed:

```
public static validate(Id accountId1, Id accountId2, Id opportunityId1) {
    Set<ID> tmp = New Set<ID>(accountID1, AccountID2); //Although you should be passing this in
    Map<ID, Account> acctMap = New Map<ID,Account>([Select ID From Account Where ID IN :tmp]);

    //Do your check
    if(acctMap.containsKey(accountID1)) { //DO something for firstID }
    if(acctMap.containsKey(accountID2)) { //DO something for Second }

    Opportunity[] opps = [Select ID From Opportunity Where ID = :opportunityid];
     if(!opps.isEmpty()) { //Opp exists }

}
```

Now, if you had an external ID field set on those objects with the IDs then you could do it with SOSL but the ID field is not search-indexed so if you are finding the ID field you are stuck with SOQL.

Comment: You are not checking opportunityId.. I'd like to check if both 3 Ids are still valid

Comment: Updated. I do not think you can do it via SOSL, although I do not use it often, my attempts to use an ID does not work and ID fields are not search-indexed so I do not think you can do it.....See updated code